# Files missing during move from SP 2007 to 2013

Tags: document, explorer-view, move, content-migration

I have moved about two thousand documents using Explorer View and the SP 2013 UI. Most of the documents have transferred successfully, however some managers are reporting files missing.

At most, 100 files were being moved into a folder at a time.

I've made sure that all documents have been checked in and ran through issues identified in other articles, but can't find a cause or solution.

We were deleting files as we moved, so I checked the Recycle bin in 2007, and could not find the files either. The server is backed up, however I'd rather solve the problem than resort to using backups.

I should also say that we've ruled out human error/the possibility that documents were actually missing in the first place as we've searched for files that were known to be on the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your file sizes? Moving them with Explorer view usually limits your move by 50MB, or something like that. 50 500kb files should not be a problem, but 3 25MB files could be a problem. Also, check the file names... specially if they got some special characters, like "-" or "_".

Answer (score 0):

Any changes to files should show up in the Change Log. There should be an add event when the file was created. You can either write [some code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447550(v=office.14).aspx) or use [PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloshm/2009/06/05/how-to-programmatically-read-the-changelog-in-powershell/) to read out the log. The log would also tell you if the file was deleted or moved after you moved your content.

Answer (score 0):

[Check your sites Recycle Bin.  If there is nothing there, check the Site Collection recycle bin.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-restore-or-delete-items-in-the-Recycle-Bin-of-a-SharePoint-site-6df466b6-55f2-4898-8d6e-c0dff851a0be)  Typically if its less than 30 days since deletion, you can restore if from one or the other.

If they are in neither of these, I recommend you restore from Backup.

Rule of thumb during any migration:  Don't delete from the source, until the customer confirms all is well at the target.

Comment: Thanks, this issue is historical now. I can't even remember how I solved it. I know that I never deleted from source and I'm sure it was a simple solution, I should have updated this entry at the time. Apologies.